# Screen Flickering issue in IOS 10.3.3 in ionic/cordova app

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm working on a hybrid app with angular using ionic/cordova frameworks, its working fine on android but showing some flickering on a screen when I run it on iPad. I've already reached the internet but couldn't find exact solution or the cause of the problem. 
Version are:

```
Angular => 5
ionic => 3.9.2
cordova => 7.0.1
iOS => 10.3
```

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

Add these two properties to prevent flickering effects:

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Please let me know if this work. Happy Coding! :)

Comment: Where exactly this supposed to be placed ?

Comment: Please can you add where to place that? Just in whole body?